# Find a rigid motion interchanging the two regions determined by the primitive surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Consider the primitive surface, that is,

$$
\mathcal{P} = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ ; \ \cos x + \cos y + \cos z = 0\}.
$$

The exercise asks for us to find a rigid motion that interchanges the two regions determined by the surface. What does it mean? How to find such a rigid motion?

Comment: This surface divides $\mathbb R^3$ into two connected components (the regions $f>0$ and $f<0$ where $f = \cos x + \cos y + \cos z.$) You should be able to use the symmetries of $\cos$ to find a translation that swaps these regions.

Comment: How can I prove that indeed these are two regions separated by $f = 0$? Is it some sort of intermediate value theorem? And would the translation be $\tau_\pi(x, y, z) = (x + \pi, y + \pi, z + \pi)$?

Comment: That translation looks right to me - can you prove that it's a bijection between $\{f>0\}$ and $\{f < 0\}$? If you want a rigorous proof that $\{ f \ne 0\}$ has two connected components given by these two regions, the easiest approach is probably to show that they are path-connected.